# String variable scope issues?

Tags: c, string, variables, scope

```
Program:
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    char x[6] = "12345\0";
    char y[6] = "67890\0";
    y[7]='A';
    printf("X: %s\n",x);
    printf("Y: %s\n",y);
}
```

**Program output:**
X: 1A345
Y: 67890

The following program defines and prints the two variables x and y and gives the above output.
Would someone please be able to explain to me why the character A appears in the output of x?

I believe this is due to the way memory is handled in C and writing outside of the bounds of y.
I am a computer science student and looking to understand why this happens. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Accessing the array out of bounds is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The memory was probably layed out like this:

```
6  7  8  9  0 \0 1  2  3  4  5 \0
y                x
```

And then `y[7]` is the same as `x[1]`

Do note that this belongs to the realm of undefined behavior. This means that your code is not required to work that way. Enabling compiler optimizations might change it. When I tried your code in `gcc`, the behavior went away with `-O2` and `-O3`.

Read more about UB here [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/6699433)